# Method not found when update contract in NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol, near, nearprotocol-validator

I have seen strange behavior when updating contracts in near(using rust)

I usually launch 1 first contract as templates, following the usual commands:

```
$ cargo new rust-myproject
cargo test -- --nocapture
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
near deploy --wasmFile target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/myproject.wasm --accountId myaccount.testnet

near call myaccount.testnet mymethod --accountId myaccount.testnet
```

So far so good, the problem comes when I want to add methods and I have to update the contract. When I update it, the new methods are not there, but I see in the near explorer how it is that if the contract was updated, it seems that the new contract is not being taken into account.

[image]

Sometimes it updates other times it doesn't update at all.

How can you be sure that the contract is the new one? I am relying on the explorer but is there another way?

Obviously when I try to call i received "Method not found"

```
type: 'MethodNotFound',
  context: undefined,
  index: 0,
  transaction_outcome: {
    proof: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    block_hash: '57ULC9DaU63hbQGPCvGVvvLh7TPVhrXSZfAqcwyvoWWz',
    id: '5EGfWdg2qWXvddT4v2JiyvzZ7Esdp5Qy4MJoo3qJvTHu',
    outcome: {
      logs: [],
      receipt_ids: [Array],
      gas_burnt: 2427950067142,
      tokens_burnt: '242795006714200000000',
      executor_id: 'josedlujan.testnet',
      status: [Object],
      metadata: [Object]
```

Comment: This happened to me yesterday as well, and I ended up deploying a new testnet contract instead.

Comment: Just wait? o repeat a different steps?

Answer (score -1):

I think every contract is unique. You cannot actually update the existing contract.

What you can do is using:

1. use dev-deploy to generate a new contract id each time
2. use your currrent account(main account) create a sub-account(sub-account) can treat as a user account/ contract .
3. Then you use this sub-acc (contract) to deploy it.

`near create-account CONTRACT_NAME.ACCOUNT_ID --masterAcount ACCOUNT_ID --initialBalance 10`

`near deploy --wasmFile target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/key_value_storage.wasm --accountId CONTRACT_ID`

You can reference this article.

https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/write-and-deploy-a-smart-contract-on-near

(I also just start to learn the Near Protocol Smart Contract. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: You can update a contract as long as you have the access keys, and the contract is not locked.

Comment: Yup, you are right. i just checked , previously i always use near-api-js, createAndDeployContract feature,  it always return a error message "AccountIsExist",  so that i assume the contract cannot be update at testnet.  thanks for point it out.

Comment: by the way, after you making changes,  you need to run cargo build command